# Pandas - read_hdf or store.select returning incorrect results for a query

Tags: python, pandas, pytables, hdf

I have a large dataset (4 million rows, 50 columns) stored via pandas store.append.  When I use either store.select or read_hdf with a query for 2 columns being greater than a certain value (i.e. "(a > 10) & (b > 1)" I get 15,000 or so rows returned.

When I read in the entire table, as say df, and do df[(df.a > 10) & (df.b > 1)] I get 30,000 rows.  I narrowed down the problem - when I read in the entire table and do df.query("(a > 10) & (b > 1)") it's the same 15,000 rows, but when I set the engine to python ---> df.query("(a > 10) & (b > 1)", engine = 'python') I get the 30,000 rows.

I suspect it has something to do with the eval/numexpr method of querying in the HDF and Query methods.

The types are float64's in columns a and b, and even if I query with a float (ie. 1. instead of 1) the problem still persists.

I would appreciate any feedback or if others have the same problem we need to fix this.

Regards,
Neil

========================

## Here's the info:

### pd.show_versions()

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS

commit: None
python: 2.7.6.final.0
python-bits: 32
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 13.3.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None

pandas: 0.14.1
nose: 1.3.3
Cython: None
numpy: 1.8.0
scipy: 0.14.0
statsmodels: 0.5.0
IPython: 1.2.1
sphinx: 1.2.2
patsy: 0.2.0
scikits.timeseries: 0.91.3
dateutil: 2.2
pytz: 2013.8
bottleneck: 0.7.0
tables: 3.1.1
numexpr: 2.4
matplotlib: 1.3.1
openpyxl: 2.0.3
xlrd: 0.9.3
xlwt: 0.7.5
xlsxwriter: 0.5.5
lxml: 3.3.5
bs4: None
html5lib: 0.95-dev
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
rpy2: None
sqlalchemy: 0.9.4
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
```

### df.info() ---> on the selected 15,000 or so rows

```
Int64Index: 15533 entries, 67302 to 142465

Data columns (total 47 columns):

date 15533 non-null datetime64[ns]
text 15533 non-null object
date2 1090 non-null datetime64[ns]
x1 15533 non-null float64
x2 15533 non-null float64
x3 15533 non-null float64
x4 15533 non-null float64
x5 15533 non-null float64
x6 15533 non-null float64
x7 15533 non-null float64
x8 15533 non-null float64
x9 15533 non-null float64
x10 15533 non-null float64
x11 15533 non-null float64
x12 15533 non-null float64
x13 15533 non-null float64
x14 15533 non-null float64
x15 15533 non-null float64
x16 15533 non-null float64
x17 15533 non-null float64
x18 15533 non-null float64
a 15533 non-null float64
x19 15533 non-null float64
x20 15533 non-null float64
x21 15533 non-null float64
x22 15533 non-null float64
x23 15533 non-null float64
x24 15533 non-null float64
b 15533 non-null float64
x25 15533 non-null float64
x26 15533 non-null float64
x27 15533 non-null float64
x28 15533 non-null float64
x29 15533 non-null float64
x30 15533 non-null float64
x31 15497 non-null float64
x32 15497 non-null float64
x33 15497 non-null float64
x34 15497 non-null float64
x35 15533 non-null int64
x36 15533 non-null int64
x37 15533 non-null int64
x38 15533 non-null int64
x39 15533 non-null int64
x40 15533 non-null int64
x41 15533 non-null int64
x42 15533 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(36), int64(8), object(1)
```

### ptdump -av file

```
/ (RootGroup) ''
/._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
[CLASS := 'GROUP',
PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.1',
TITLE := '',
VERSION := '1.0']
/MKT (Group) ''
/MKT._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 14 attributes:
[CLASS := 'GROUP',
TITLE := '',
VERSION := '1.0',
data_columns := ['date', 'text', 'a', 'x20', 'x23', 'x24', 'b', 'x25', 'x26', 'x35', 'x36', 'x37', 'x38', 'x39', 'x40', 'x41', 'x42'],
encoding := None,
index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
info := {1: {'type': 'Index', 'names': [None]}, 'index': {}},
levels := 1,
nan_rep := 'nan',
non_index_axes := [(1, ['date', 'text', 'date2', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'x10', 'x11', 'x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15', 'x16', 'x17', 'x18', 'a', 'x19', 'x20', 'x21', 'x22', 'x23', 'x24', 'b', 'x25', 'x26', 'x27', 'x28', 'x29', 'x30', 'x31', 'x32', 'x33', 'x34', 'x35', 'x36', 'x37', 'x38', 'x39', 'x40', 'x41', 'x42'])],
pandas_type := 'frame_table',
pandas_version := '0.10.1',
table_type := 'appendable_frame',
values_cols := ['values_block_0', 'values_block_1', 'date', 'text', 'a', 'x20', 'x23', 'x24', 'b', 'x25', 'x26', 'x35', 'x36', 'x37', 'x38', 'x39', 'x40', 'x41', 'x42']]
/MKT/table (Table(3637597,)) ''
description := {
"index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
"values_block_0": Int64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=1),
"values_block_1": Float64Col(shape=(29,), dflt=0.0, pos=2),
"date": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=3),
"text": StringCol(itemsize=30, shape=(), dflt='', pos=4),
"a": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=5),
"x20": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=6),
"x23": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=7),
"x24": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=8),
"b": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=9),
"x25": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=10),
"x26": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=11),
"x35": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=12),
"x36": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=13),
"x37": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=14),
"x38": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=15),
"x39": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=16),
"x40": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=17),
"x41": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=18),
"x42": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=19)}
byteorder := 'little'
chunkshape := (322,)
autoindex := True
colindexes := {
"x41": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x20": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x37": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x42": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x26": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x38": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x40": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"date": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x36": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"text": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x23": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x39": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x25": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x24": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"a": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"x35": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
"b": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
/MKT/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 83 attributes:
[CLASS := 'TABLE',
x23_dtype := 'float64',
x23_kind := ['x23'],
x20_dtype := 'float64',
x20_kind := ['x20'],
FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
FIELD_10_FILL := 0.0,
FIELD_10_NAME := 'x25',
FIELD_11_FILL := 0.0,
FIELD_11_NAME := 'x26',
FIELD_12_FILL := 0,
FIELD_12_NAME := 'x35',
FIELD_13_FILL := 0,
FIELD_13_NAME := 'x36',
FIELD_14_FILL := 0,
FIELD_14_NAME := 'x37',
FIELD_15_FILL := 0,
FIELD_15_NAME := 'x38',
FIELD_16_FILL := 0,
FIELD_16_NAME := 'x39',
FIELD_17_FILL := 0,
FIELD_17_NAME := 'x40',
FIELD_18_FILL := 0,
FIELD_18_NAME := 'x41',
FIELD_19_FILL := 0,
FIELD_19_NAME := 'x42',
FIELD_1_FILL := 0,
FIELD_1_NAME := 'values_block_0',
FIELD_2_FILL := 0.0,
FIELD_2_NAME := 'values_block_1',
FIELD_3_FILL := 0,
FIELD_3_NAME := 'date',
FIELD_4_FILL := '',
FIELD_4_NAME := 'text',
FIELD_5_FILL := 0.0,
FIELD_5_NAME := 'a',
FIELD_6_FILL := 0.0,
FIELD_6_NAME := 'x20',
FIELD_7_FILL := 0.0,
FIELD_7_NAME := 'x23',
FIELD_8_FILL := 0.0,
FIELD_8_NAME := 'x24',
FIELD_9_FILL := 0.0,
FIELD_9_NAME := 'b',
a_dtype := 'float64',
a_kind := ['a'],
NROWS := 3637597,
TITLE := '',
VERSION := '2.7',
x24_dtype := 'float64',
x24_kind := ['x24'],
b_dtype := 'float64',
b_kind := ['b'],
x25_dtype := 'float64',
x25_kind := ['x25'],
x26_dtype := 'float64',
x26_kind := ['x26'],
date_dtype := 'datetime64',
date_kind := ['date'],
x39_dtype := 'int64',
x39_kind := ['x39'],
x37_dtype := 'int64',
x37_kind := ['x37'],
x41_dtype := 'int64',
x41_kind := ['x41'],
x35_dtype := 'int64',
x35_kind := ['x35'],
x40_dtype := 'int64',
x40_kind := ['x40'],
x38_dtype := 'int64',
x38_kind := ['x38'],
x42_dtype := 'int64',
x42_kind := ['x42'],
x36_dtype := 'int64',
x36_kind := ['x36'],
index_kind := 'integer',
text_dtype := 'string240',
text_kind := ['text'],
values_block_0_dtype := 'datetime64',
values_block_0_kind := ['date2'],
values_block_1_dtype := 'float64',
values_block_1_kind := ['x22', 'x18', 'x21', 'x16', 'x19', 'x17', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'x29', 'x30', 'x28', 'x2', 'x1', 'x3', 'x10', 'x27', 'x11', 'x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15', 'x33', 'x32', 'x34', 'x31']]
```

## Here's how I read in the table:

```
df = DataFrame()store = pd.HDFStore('/Users/neil/MKT.h5')
df = store.select('MKT', "(a > 10) & (b > 1)")
store.close()
```

## Here's how I write/fill the table:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('/Users/neil/MKT.h5')

listofsearchablevars = ['date', 'text', 'a', 'x20', 'x23', 'x24', 'b', 'x25', 'x26', 'x35', 'x36', 'x37', 'x38', 'x39', 'x40', 'x41', 'x42']

df = .....

store.append('MKT', df, data_columns = listofsearchablevars, nan_rep = 'nan', chunksize=500000, min_itemsize = {'values': 30})

store.close()
```

EDIT: response to request to provide some sample data....

### Data

For clarity,
let's call the 15,000 result: "INCORRECT"
let's call the 30,000 result: "CORRECT"
let's call items in CORRECT but not in INCORRECT: "Only in CORRECT"

I have confirmed, that all rows/items in INCORRECT are completely found
in CORRECT.

## Here's a couple of rows of data in each (just took rows 10000 and 10001 of each):

### Only in CORRECT:

```
                    9869                 9870
date   2001-08-10 00:00:00  2001-08-17 00:00:00
text                   DCR                  DCR
date2                  NaN                  NaN
x19                    1.9               1.8396
x18                   1.98                  1.9
x20                    1.8                  1.8
x9                    2.54                 2.54
x10                   5.25                5.125
x11                  9.625                9.625
x12                   1.61                  1.7
x13                   1.05                 1.05
x14                   1.05                 1.05
x21                  75700                64800
x23               140992.7             116948.9
x24           0.0008284454         0.0007097211
x25            0.002580505          0.002630241
x26            0.001540047          0.001440302
x27            0.001850877          0.001832468
x5                  17.915               17.915
x8                  17.915               17.915
x2                 34.0379              32.9563
a                  34.0385             32.95643
x6               -42.80079            -42.80079
x7               -8.762288            -9.844354
x4                       0                    0
x1           -0.0003349149        -0.0003349149
x3           -0.0003349149        -0.0003349149
x28              1.579e+07            1.579e+07
b                 1.261029             1.302433
x29               1.284075             1.326236
x30               1.488814             1.537697
x22             -0.2891579           -0.3205045
x17                   0.31                 0.31
x15                   0.84                 0.84
x16                 2.5937               2.5937
x34                  6.895                7.105
x32               -1.29055             -1.35055
x31                  -0.77                -0.63
x33                 -0.665                -0.49
x38                      1                    1
x42                      0                    0
x36                      0                    0
x40                      0                    0
x35                      0                    0
x39                      0                    0
x37                      0                    0
x41                      0                    0
```

### INCORRECT:

```
                    153641               153642
date   2008-08-22 00:00:00  2008-08-29 00:00:00
text                   PRL                  PRL
date2                  NaN                  NaN
x19                    1.9                 1.88
x18                   1.95                 1.94
x20                   1.85                 1.87
x9                    2.07                 2.07
x10                   2.23                 2.23
x11                   2.94                 2.94
x12                   1.75                 1.75
x13                   1.71                 1.71
x14                   1.69                 1.69
x21                 133549                73525
x23               254119.1             140764.5
x24            0.001485416         0.0008315729
x25            0.001227271          0.001204803
x26            0.001006876          0.001048327
x27           0.0009764919         0.0009638125
x5                  18.008               18.008
x8                  18.058               18.058
x2                 34.2152               33.855
a                  34.3102             33.94904
x6               -35.07229            -35.07229
x7              -0.7620911            -1.123251
x4                       0                    0
x1               0.0111308            0.0111308
x3               0.0111308            0.0111308
x28             1.5488e+08           1.5488e+08
b                 1.251983             1.265302
x29               1.272828             1.286369
x30               1.247996             1.261273
x22              0.1368421            0.1489362
x17                   0.16                 0.16
x15                    0.2                  0.2
x16                   0.47                 0.47
x34                   2.25                 2.34
x32                  1.395                1.365
x31                   1.25                 1.31
x33                  1.175                 1.25
x38                      1                    1
x42                      0                    0
x36                      0                    0
x40                      0                    0
x35                      0                    0
x39                      0                    0
x37                      0                    0
x41                      0                    0
```

### CORRECT:

```
                    99723                99725
date   2009-11-27 00:00:00  2009-12-11 00:00:00
text                   ACL                  ACL
date2                  NaN                  NaN
x19                   1.17                  1.2
x18                   1.22                 1.39
x20                   1.11                 1.14
x9                    1.76                 1.76
x10                   1.76                 1.76
x11                   1.76                 1.76
x12                   0.63                 0.74
x13                   0.36                 0.36
x14                   0.17                 0.17
x21                 285474               709374
x23               333678.1             868999.7
x24           0.0005489386          0.001393863
x25            0.002350057          0.002279827
x26            0.002160912          0.002111369
x27            0.002428953          0.002244943
x5                 103.908              103.908
x8                 103.908              103.908
x2                121.5721             124.6894
a                 121.5724             124.6896
x6                92.16074             92.16074
x7                213.7331             216.8503
x4                       0                    0
x1            -0.008266928         -0.008266928
x3            -0.008266928         -0.008266928
x28             0.02743141           0.02703708
b                 1.037747             1.011804
x29               1.421532             1.385994
x30                1.52714             1.488961
x22               1.213675                  1.7
x17                   0.47                 0.47
x15                   0.48                 0.48
x16                   0.48                 0.48
x34                   0.32                 0.32
x32                   1.04                 1.04
x31                   -0.6                 -0.6
x33                -0.5901               -0.479
x38                      0                    0
x42                      0                    0
x36                      0                    0
x40                      0                    0
x35                      0                    0
x39                      0                    0
x37                      0                    0
x41                      0                    0
```

Comment: post: pandas,numpy,pytables versions. df.info(), ptdump -av <file>, and exact code for storage and query

Answer (score 0):

SUCESS!!!!! I filled all NaNs in the data and now the read_hdf where returns the correct 30,000 rows.  column a had NaNs (which was one of the data_columns in the query, a > 10).  Man, that was painful.  FYI - because of my paranoia, to get rid of any possible circumstance that this could repeat itself in the future, I completely fillna(0) the entire table as I cannot risk reaching conclusions from this analysis with an incorrect or incomplete query from the table.  It was a NaN issue for sure.

Comment: Glad that you nailed down the problem.  And yes, NaN are tricky values to handle.